# Is there a word or phrase that means "both literally and figuratively"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The question is simple:  is there a word or phrase that means "both literally and figuratively", aside from the one I just used?

Comment: Although, on the face of it, your question *is* simple, it would be useful to have some context. Could you give a sentence with a blank where the word would go? Examples are always helpful.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Man is rowing a canoe upstream.  Man drops paddle, and it floats away.  Man is literally and figuratively up the creek without a paddle.  Or, sailor hoists three sails, but is too drunk to point them away from the wind..  Sailor is literally and figuratively three sheets to the wind.  Or, man gets bitten by his dog while drunk.  The next morning, he is hungover.  He makes a Bloody Mary and adds some fur from his dog.  Man is literally and figuratively having the hair of the dog that bit him.